# Products formed when solid CuCN is dissolved in aqueous KCN solution

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds

Copper cyanide forms a complex coordination compound, when dissolved in a solution containing excess ($\ce{CN^-}$) ions.

My question is whether it forms $\ce{[Cu(CN)_4]^{3-}}$ only or both $\ce{[Cu(CN)_3]^{2-}}$ and $\ce{[Cu(CN)_4]^{3-}}$ complexes?

Wikipedia says that both complexes are formed, but I am not sure if its a reliable source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, both $\ce{[Cu(CN)3]^2-}$  and $\ce{[Cu(CN)4]^3-}$ species are formed. According to Wikipedia article of [copper cyanide](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copper%28I%29_cyanide?wprov=sfla1):

> ... **but rapidly dissolves in solutions containing $\ce{CN−}$ to form
>   $\ce{[Cu(CN)3]^2-}$ and $\ce{[Cu(CN)4]^3-}$, which exhibit trigonal
>   planar and tetrahedral coordination geometry, respectively.** These
>   complexes contrast with those of silver and gold cyanides, which form
>   $\ce{[M(CN)2]−}$ ions in solution.The coordination polymer
>   $\ce{KCu(CN)2}$ contains $\ce{[Cu(CN)2]−}$ units, which link together
>   forming helical anionic chains.

See [this paper](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ic50226a022) for more details.